# How to make the order of async function executions in Flutter consistent?

Tags: json, flutter, dart, asynchronous, async-await

In the quiz app I'm making, this controller reads a local JSON item and creates a shuffled list with eight items inside. Then, a session screen is launched with the said list to be used in making the UI.

```
class SessionController{

  List _currentSessionList = [];
  
  SessionController(BuildContext context, String lessonID) {
    readJsonForItems(lessonID);
    launchSessionScreen(context, lessonID);
    int _currentSessionIndex = 0;
  }

  SessionController.feature();

  Future<void> readJsonForItems(String lessonID) async {
    final String response = await rootBundle.loadString('assets/model/complete_items.json');
    final listFromJson = await json.decode(response);
    createSessionList(listFromJson, lessonID);
  }

  void createSessionList(var importedList, String lessonID) async {
    var sessionItems = importedList[lessonID];
    sessionItems.shuffle();

    _currentSessionList = List.from(sessionItems.take(8));
  }

  void launchSessionScreen(BuildContext context, String lessonID) async {
    Navigator.push( context,
        MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => SessionScreen(_currentSessionList, lessonID)),
      );
  }

  List getCurrentSessionList() {
    return _currentSessionList;
  }

  int getCurrentSessionIndex() {
    return _currentSessionIndex;
  }
```

Here is the code for the SessionScreen class:

```
class SessionScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  List currentSessionList;
  String lessonID;
  List currentLessonContents;

  SessionScreen(this.currentSessionList, this.lessonID, this.currentLessonContents, {super.key});

  @override
  State<SessionScreen> createState() => _SessionScreenState();
}

class _SessionScreenState extends State<SessionScreen> {
  late List sessionItems;
  String lessonID = "", question = "", prompt = "", correctAnswer = "";
  List<dynamic> choices = [];

  @override
  void initState(){
    super.initState();
    setInitialContents();
  }

  void setInitialContents() async {
    sessionItems = List.from(widget.currentSessionList);
    updateContents();
  }

  void updateContents() async {
    int index = feature.getCurrentSessionIndex();
        setState(() {
          question = sessionItems[index]["question"];
          prompt = sessionItems[index]["prompt"];
          choices = sessionItems[index]["choices"];
          correctAnswer = sessionItems[index]["correct_answer"];
          audioFileDirectory = sessionItems[index]["audio_file"];
        });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext buildContext) {

    return MaterialApp(
        home: Scaffold(
          backgroundColor: const Color(0xffF5F1E6),
          appBar: sessionAppBar(fromCompletionScreen: false, context: context),
          body: Center(
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
            children: <Widget>[
              Container(
                width: 400,
                margin: const EdgeInsets.all(30),
                  child: Column(
                  children: <Widget> [
                    // I removed the other UI components for brevity's sake.
                    ),
                  ]
                  ),
                ),
            ],
            ),
          ),
        )
        );
  }
```

These are the issues:

1. **In the first session, **the program builds the SessionScreen prematurely, without the list of contents like the question, prompt, choices, etc. Because of this, the widgets are loaded, but they are empty.
2. However, if this session is quitted and a new session starts, the screen already works as expected. So, **from the second session onwards, the list of contents are already loaded with the UI and works as expected.**

Clearly, there is an issue with the first session. What am I missing here?

I tried loading the JSON file from the launching of the app, but still, getting the JSON contents and loading them on the screen are late in the first session. I'm new to asynchronous programming, so thank you for you patience. :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several issues with the code presented.

1. `readJsonForItems()` is asynchronous, but it is not `await`ed in the `SessionController` constructor. Therefore, **`launchSessionScreen()` may be called before `readJsonForItems()` has completed**. Note that constructors cannot be asynchronous. So for `SessionController`, consider splitting the concepts of *construction* and *initialization*. Maybe something like

```dart
  SessionController() {
    int _currentSessionIndex = 0;
  }

  Future<void> start(BuildContext context, String lessonID) async {
    await readJsonForItems(lessonID);
    launchSessionScreen(context, lessonID);
  }
```

1B. While you're learning asynchronous programming in Dart, consider adding the following to `analysis_options.yaml` to help catch issues like the foregoing:

```yaml
linter:
  rules:
    unawaited_futures: true
```

2. Typically, when the UI depends on an asynchronous result, you will need to use a *builder* of some sort. The builder helps you create the UI after the asynchronous operation upon which the UI depends has completed. In the case presented, [FutureBuilder](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/FutureBuilder-class.html) would be an appropriate choice.

How you do this will depend on what you want to achieve, but one possibility might look like this:

```dart
  Future<List> readJsonForItems(String lessonID) async {
    final String response = await rootBundle.loadString('assets/model/complete_items.json');
    final listFromJson = await json.decode(response);
    return createSessionList(listFromJson, lessonID);
  }

  List createSessionList(var importedList, String lessonID) {
    var sessionItems = importedList[lessonID];
    sessionItems.shuffle();
    return List.from(sessionItems.take(8));
  }

  void launchSessionScreen(BuildContext context, String lessonID) async {
    Navigator.push(
      context,
      MaterialPageRoute(
        builder: (context) {
          return FutureBuilder(
            future: readJsonForItems(lessonID),
            builder: (context, snapshot) {
              if (snapshot.hasData) {
                return SessionScreen(snapshot.data, lessonID);  
              }
              else {
                return SizedBox.shrink();
              }
            }
          );
        } 
      ),
    );
  }
```

In this example, you'd call `launchSessionScreen()` to start a lesson. It kicks of the asynchronous call (`readJsonForItems(lessonID)`), and uses a `FutureBuilder` to show nothing before the future has completed, and a `SessionScreen` containing the loaded list after the future has completed.

(You could substitute a loading spinner in place of `SizedBox.shrink()` to offer some feedback to the user.)

3. `createSessionList()` and `launchSessionScreen()` are marked `async` but should not be. They're not asynchronous.

Comment: I have already separated the start method from the constructor. But, given the code snippet I gave above, where should I call the start function you suggested? Also, how can I use the FutureBuilder inside the SessionScreen if this screen has only been pushed from the SessionController with the future methods? Unfortunately, the unawaited_futures parameter does not do anything on the IDE. Thank you in advance.

Comment: @egm_along Updated the answer with one possible approach.

Comment: Thank you so much for your guidance! I adopted your approach, and it worked.